# Can we add ibm-pcjr and tandy-pc tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Could we add the following tags?  Either as parent tags or synonyms:

`ibm-pcjr`  (or, would `ibm-pc-jr` be better?)

`tandy-pc`

Answer (score 5):

The system doesn't allow one to create tags except if they have at least one question; any tags that are created will be treated as orphaned and automatically deleted after 24 hours.

I see that you have posted [this question](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2383/278); I've added the [ibm-pcjr](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibm-pcjr) and [tandy-1000](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tandy-1000) tags to it, thus creating the tags. I'm not sure that [ibm-pc-tandy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibm-pc-tandy) is right, as IBM didn't manufacture it. I think that [tandy-1000](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tandy-1000) would be better (compare: [apple-ii](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-ii)).

Comment: I'd say [tag:ibm-pcjr] to keep with the manufacturer-modelname paradigm, and maybe [tag:ibm-pc-tandy] to show that its a compatible derivative?

Comment: @mnem I think that [tag:tandy-1000] would be better than [tag:ibm-pc-tandy]; if the PC-compatibleness is particularly important the [tag:ibm-pc] tag should be used as well.

Comment: Good point.  Tandy-1000 is more descriptive of the whole line, and less awkward.